# How to define relation through another relation in Laravel like via() in Yii2?

Tags: php, laravel

I need to define one relation through another relation in Laravel so both relations can be eagerly loaded in the optimal way.

For example I have `item` and `attr` tables with `attr_item` intermediate table. In Yii2 I can define one relation through another by using method `via`:

```
class Item extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function getAttrItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(AttrItem::class, ['item_id' => 'id']);
    }

    public function getAttrs()
    {
        return $this-hasMany(Attr::class, ['id' => 'attr_id'])->via('attrItems');
    }
}
```

So when I call `$item = Item::find()->with('attrs')->where(['id' => 1])->one()` Yii2 makes two additional queries: to table `attr_item` with condition `item_id = 1` and to table `attr` with identifiers found in previous query. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM "item" WHERE "id"=1
SELECT * FROM "attr_item" WHERE "item_id"=1
SELECT * FROM "attr" WHERE "id" IN (1, 2, 3)
```

After that I have two populated relations: `$item->attrs` and `$item->attrItems`.

But I didn't found the same functionality in Laravel. I can define `$this->hasManyThrough(Attr::class, AttrItem::class, 'item_id', 'id', 'id', 'attr_id')` or `$this->belongsToMany(Attr::class, 'attr_item', 'item_id', 'attr_id', 'id', 'id')` in `Item` class but it makes just one query to DB like:

```
select 
  "attr".*, 
  "attr_item"."item_id" as "pivot_item_id", 
  "attr_item"."attr_id" as "pivot_attr_id" 
from 
  "attr" 
  inner join "attr_item" on "attr"."id" = "attr_item"."attr_id" 
where 
  "attr_item"."item_id" = '1';
```

And of course it doesn't hydrate `attrItems` relation because there is no information about intermediate relation. I can eagerly load both relations `attrs` and `attrItems` but in this case the intermediate table `attr_item` will be used twice and that is not good for performance.

Answer (score 0):

Im not quite sure if this is what you mean but have you looked at 'nested eager loading morph to relationships'?

https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Scroll down a bit for 'nested eager loading morph to relationships'.